# Nexus 5X stays awake after charging

Tags: charging, sleep, nexus-5x

Nexus 5X running 6.0.1 shows awake after disconnecting charger cable.

**Reboot helps** but later the awake state persists if I connect charger back.

[image]

Comment: I think its a issue with the dose system

Comment: Thx! Any ideas on how to fix? Later I could try complete reset but it would be better to know the root cause.

Comment: Turn off doze and try

Comment: As far as I remember there is no such control in Settings. If you mean "Battery saver" - it is OFF by default.

Comment: Factory data reset helped but didn't help to know the root-cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the root cause for awake state - it is **Viber**.
To detect this I've completely removed all third party software and left only one came from Google (my Nexus 5X comes only with Google and no bloatware).

So adding apps one by one I was checking the issue appearance after every.
The issue back after adding **Viber** and immediately has gone after removing it.